# Difficulties in Printing HTML Table where cell is having row span which is more than the height of the page

Tags: html, html-table

Below is the table code while printing this code I found issues after page break.

While I print the table in the 2nd column where Institute names are there it cell is having row span according to its next level values of rows. In some cases row span is more than the height of the page so while printing table this cell is spanning across the pages but some rows gets their positions changed after it.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    tr,
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    td,
    th {
      padding: 3px;
    }

    table {
      page-break-inside: auto
    }

    tr {
      page-break-inside: avoid;
      page-break-after: auto
    }

    thead {
      display: table-header-group
    }

    tfoot {
      display: table-footer-group
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan=1>Sr.</th>
        <th rowspan=1>Institute_Name</th>
        <th rowspan=1>Department_Name</th>
        <th rowspan=1>Shift</th>
        <th rowspan=1>Category</th>
        <th colspan=1>Female</th>
        <th colspan=1>Male</th>
        <th class="fw-bold bg-dark-subtle" rowspan=1>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=18>1</td>
        <td rowspan=18>Business Administration</td>
        <td rowspan=11>BBA</td>
        <td rowspan=5>Evening</td>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SC</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SEBC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ST</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=5>Morning</td>
        <td>EWS</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ST</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Total</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=6>MBA</td>
        <td rowspan=5>Evening</td>
        <td>EWS</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SEBC</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=3>Total</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=40>2</td>
        <td rowspan=40>DIET</td>
        <td rowspan=7>Civil</td>
        <td rowspan=4>Evening</td>
        <td>SC</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SEBC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ST</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>Morning</td>
        <td>SC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Total</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=7>Computer</td>
        <td rowspan=4>Evening</td>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SC</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SEBC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>Morning</td>
        <td>SEBC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=8>Electrical</td>
        <td rowspan=4>Evening</td>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SC</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ST</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=3>Morning</td>
        <td>EWS</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ST</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Total</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=9>Information Technology</td>
        <td rowspan=4>Evening</td>
        <td>EWS</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ST</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=4>Morning</td>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SC</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ST</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Total</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=8>Mechanical</td>
        <td rowspan=3>Evening</td>
        <td>EWS</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SEBC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=4>Morning</td>
        <td>EWS</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SEBC</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Total</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=3>Total</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=38>3</td>
        <td rowspan=38>DIETDS</td>
        <td rowspan=8>Civil</td>
        <td rowspan=3>Evening</td>
        <td>EWS</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SEBC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=4>Morning</td>
        <td>EWS</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SEBC</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Total</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=9>Computer</td>
        <td rowspan=4>Evening</td>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ST</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=4>Morning</td>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SEBC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=7>Electrical</td>
        <td rowspan=4>Evening</td>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ST</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>Morning</td>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=6>Information Technology</td>
        <td rowspan=2>Evening</td>
        <td>EWS</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=3>Morning</td>
        <td>EWS</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ST</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Total</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=7>Mechanical</td>
        <td rowspan=4>Evening</td>
        <td>SC</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SEBC</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ST</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>Morning</td>
        <td>ST</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Total</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=3>Total</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=31>4</td>
        <td rowspan=31>SOE</td>
        <td rowspan=9>Civil</td>
        <td rowspan=3>Evening</td>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SEBC</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=1>Total</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan=5>Morning</td>
        <td>EWS</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>OPEN</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking. Can you rephrase or show a picture of what you expect?